Syncfusion asp.net grid didn't show data
I am developing a small application in Syncfusion ASP.NET Core using the Grid control. My goal is to display data in the grid using the following setup:
<ejs-grid id="SourcingGrid" dataSource="@Url.Action("GetSourcingData", "Home")" allowPaging="true" toolbar="@(new List<string> { "Add", "Edit", "Delete", "Update", "Cancel" })">
    <e-grid-editSettings allowAdding="true" allowEditing="true" allowDeleting="true"></e-grid-editSettings>
    <e-grid-columns>
        <e-grid-column field="Sourcing_Fullname" headerText="Full Name" width="150" textAlign="Left"></e-grid-column>
        <e-grid-column field="Sourcing_Address" headerText="Address" width="150" textAlign="Left"></e-grid-column>
        <e-grid-column field="Sourcing_Mobile_no" headerText="Mobile No" width="120" textAlign="Left"></e-grid-column>
        <e-grid-column field="Sourcing_Email" headerText="Email" width="150" textAlign="Left"></e-grid-column>
        <e-grid-column field="Status" headerText="Status" width="80" textAlign="Center" type="boolean"></e-grid-column>
        <e-grid-column field="Blacklisted" headerText="Blacklisted" width="100" textAlign="Center" type="boolean"></e-grid-column>
        <e-grid-column field="Remarks" headerText="Remarks" width="150" textAlign="Left"></e-grid-column>
    </e-grid-columns>
</ejs-grid>

In my controller, I have the following action method:
public IActionResult GetSourcingData()
{
    var sourcingData = _sourcingDAL.GetAllSourcingAsync();
    return Json(sourcingData);
}

And in my data access layer, I have this asynchronous method:
public async Task<IEnumerable<Sourcing>> GetAllSourcingAsync()
{
    var sourcings = new List<Sourcing>();
    using (var connectionManager = new DatabaseConnectionManager(_connectionString))
    {
        using (var con = connectionManager.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_SOURCING_DETAIL", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROC", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;

                // Open connection if it's not already open
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    await con.OpenAsync();
                }

                using var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                while (await rdr.ReadAsync())
                {
                    sourcings.Add(new Sourcing
                    {
                        Sourcing_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Sourcing_Id"]),
                        Sourcing_Fullname = rdr["Sourcing_Fullname"].ToString(),
                        Sourcing_Address = rdr["Sourcing_Address"].ToString(),
                        Sourcing_Mobile_no = rdr["Sourcing_Mobile_no"].ToString(),
                        Sourcing_Contact_no = rdr["Sourcing_Contact_no"].ToString(),
                        Sourcing_Email = rdr["Sourcing_Email"].ToString(),
                        Status = rdr["Status"] != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Status"]),
                        Remarks = rdr["Remarks"] != DBNull.Value ? rdr["Remarks"].ToString() : string.Empty,
                        Blacklisted = rdr["Blacklisted"] != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Blacklisted"])
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sourcings;
}

However, when I run the project, neither the data nor the grid is displayed.
Issues Encountered:

When inspecting requests in Developer Tools, I see an error message:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
This points to a problem with the following line:
"dataSource": /Home/GetSourcingData,


Could anyone help me identify the issue and suggest possible fixes? Thank you!
What I've Tried:

Checked the URL in the browser to ensure it resolves correctly.

Verified that the GetSourcingData method is being called (it isn't).

Made sure all necessary libraries for Syncfusion and ASP.NET Core are included.


I expected the following:

When the page loads, the GetSourcingData method should be invoked, retrieving the data from the database.

The data should be returned as JSON, which the Syncfusion Grid would then use to populate the grid with rows displaying the sourced data.

The grid should render correctly on the page, allowing for interaction (like paging, editing, and deleting).



could you try setting the action url like this: <ejs-grid id="SourcingGrid" dataSource="@(Url.Action("GetSourcingData", "Home"))" allowPaging="true" toolbar="@(new List<string> { "Add", "Edit", "Delete", "Update", "Cancel" })">
